# Displaying folium marker with animated marker icon

Tags: python, folium

I am trying to plot the shapefile which is getting updated in real time on to the folium maps using the below code:

```
import folium
import geopandas as gpd

m = folium.Map(location = [13.0, 77.0], tiles=None, zoom_start = 5, control_scale = True)
gdf = gpd.read_file("Path to SHP file")

gdf_to_plot_1 = gdf[:-1]

gdf_to_plot_2 = gdf.tail(1)
gdf_to_plot_2.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)

icon_path = r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\Icons\icon.png'
lat_long_list_1 = [[point.xy[1][0], point.xy[0][0]] for point in gdf_to_plot_1.geometry]

# Iterate through list and add a marker for each volcano, color-coded by its type.
i = 0
for coordinates in lat_long_list_1:
    # Place the markers with the popup labels and data
    m.add_child(
        folium.Marker(
            location=coordinates,
            popup="Posn. Info.: "
            + str(gdf_to_plot_1['Posn_Info'][i])
            + "<br>"
            + "Data Date: "
            + str(gdf_to_plot_1['Data Date'][i])
            + "<br>"
            + "Data Time: "
            + str(gdf_to_plot_1['Data Time'][i])
            + "<br>"
            + "Coordinates: "
            + str(lat_long_list_1[i]),
            icon = folium.features.CustomIcon(icon_image=icon_path, icon_size=(25, 25)),
        )
    )
    i = i + 1
```

In the above code gdf_to_plot_1 contains all the past events and gdf_to_plot_2 contains the recent event.

With the above code I am successfully able to display gdf_to_plot_1 with all the marker plotted on the map as fixed marker.

What I want to do now is that I want to plot gdf_to_plot_2 whose marker location should be animated/flashing/blinking indicating that it is the latest location of the object.

Can someone please suggest how it can be done.